# CSS for asp hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, css

I've got CSS that looks like this:

```
a.HyperLinkHover
{
        color: #95FBCF; 
        background-color:#ff0;
        background-color: #377CB1;  
}

a.HyperLinkHover:visited { color:Purple;}
```

But when I click my `<asp:HyperLink>` where it is defined as:

`<asp:Hyperlink runat=server id=hlfile cssclass=HyperlinkHover />`

it does not have a purple color for being visited.
I assume I did it wrong ?

Comment: Try testing by changing visited to 'hover', and see if it turns purple on rollover

Answer (score 8, accepted):

unless you have a copy paste error then your cssClass doesnt match the CssDefinition

One has an uppercase Link and the other has a lower case link in HyperLinkHover

```
a.HyperLinkHover {
     color: #95FBCF;
     background-color:#ff0;
     background-color: #377CB1;   }  

a.HyperLinkHover:visited { color:Purple;}
/* hover style would come after visited */
```

and make sure the CssClass is defined with the same capitalisation

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat=server id=hlfile cssClass="HyperLinkHover" />
```

Comment: I tried this: `<asp:HyperLink ID="hlFile" runat="server" CssClass="HyperlinkHover"
                                        Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" Target="_blank" Visible="False" Font-Underline="True" ToolTip="Click to open header attachment.">[hlFile]</asp:HyperLink>` and in my css I have this `a.HyperlinkHover{color: #95FBCF;}

a.HyperlinkHover:visited {color:Purple;}

a.HyperlinkHover:hover {color: Navy;}` the only thing that looks right is the font color....

Comment: he's saying that your `cssClass="HyperlinkHover"` should be `cssClass="HyperLinkHover"`, note the capitalization of the `L` in `HyperLinkHover`